# How to prevent a dialog from closing when hitting enter or escape?

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, modeless, dm-script

I have a dialog that I would like to stay open except if the [x] or exit buttons are clicked. Dialogs seem to always close if you hit escape or if you hit enter when most objects are selected (e.g. string boxes), whether you use pose() or display(). Is there a way to prevent this?

Some public examples of when this occurs are DM Mitchell's "Example: Thread and Dialog Interaction" and "Example: Single Button Dialog" but it seems to apply to any dialog.

The exception seems to be a docked palette, but this functionality seems to be rather limited in GMS2.3/GMS3.

Example code to test:

```
class myUItest:UIframe
{
    object Init( object self )
    {
        TagGroup dlgTGitems 
        TagGroup dlgTG = DLGCreateDialog("Modal",dlgTGitems)
        TagGroup dlgField = DLGCreateIntegerField(12,20)
        dlgTGitems.DLGAddElement(dlgField)
        return self.super.init(dlgTG)
    }
}

{
    object DLG = ALLOC(myUItest).Init()
    DLG.Pose()
    DLG.display("Modeless")
}
```

Comment: Very good question, thanks. I *think* the answer is currenlty "No", as script-dialogs can not intercept keystrokes, but I will investigate this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to prevent termination of modal dialogs (those presented via the Pose method of UIFrame) via the keystrokes you mention.  However, would a modeless dialog work for your application?  Such a dialog is created by invoking the Display method on your UIFrame object and it is not closed via esc or enter.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific. I am invoking using the Display() method, similar to the examples i mentioned. They also close with esc or enter. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  This appears to be new behavior in GMS 3.  When I run the test script in GMS 2.3.2 (888), the modeless dialog does not close when I hit 'esc' or 'enter'.  It also seems that GMS 3 links default key actions to a single button (or perhaps the current default button).  Hitting either 'enter' or 'space' seems to click the button.  GMS 2.3.2 does not seem to do this.  This changed behavior will certainly have an impact on several of my scripts.  Hopefully there will be a way to get around it.

Comment: @AWag The changed behavior for modeless dialogs is a reported bug for the GMS 3 release and will be reverted to GMS 2 behavior. An additional feature-request to allow general intercepting of keystrokes from script-dialogs has been filed as well, thanks to this question here.